# Angular 2 ng-bootstrap,NgbTabset Error:Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'templateRef' of undefined

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap-tab

I try to use NgTabset but i get this error *TypeError: Cannot read property 'templateRef' of undefined* .When i replace the *ng-template* with the *template* tag everything works fine .What am i doing wrong? 
Here is the code:

```
<ngb-tabset>
  <ngb-tab>
    <ng-template ngbTabTitle>
      Tab1
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>
      Here is tab 1
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-tab>
</ngb-tabset>
```

Comment: Sounds like a dependency error. Either you are missing an import from the module, or you need to update your version of Angular.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to know without a Plunkr, but be sure to set templateRef and the #

```
<app-content [templateRef]="nestedComponentRef"></app-content>
<template #nestedComponentRef>
    <component>
    </component>
</template>
```

Here's an example: https://embed.plnkr.co/zsG5ROJD1jYVIoXaR9Ga/

Answer (score 0):

The comment by David Aguirre suggested this is a dependency issue, but it seems to due at least in part to the ng-bootstrap version.

I had this same problem and noticed that my version of ng-bootstrap was 1.0.0-alpha.24, but in the example at https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/app/components/tabset/demos/basic/plnkr.html the line in config.js was `'@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap': 'npm:@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-alpha.28/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js'`

When I lowered that version number to 1.0.0-alpha.24 I got the bunch of error messages below.

Making the change up to 1.0.0-alpha.28 worked in the version of our code on the Web, but in the code in the VCCode development environment I found that just changing `<template>` to `<ng-template>` and

```
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-alpha.24",
```

in package.json to

```
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-alpha.28",
```

was not enough to fix the problem, but creating a new CLI instance fixed the problem, so there must be some other dependency that I didn't find.

The warning at https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/app/components/tabset/demos/basic/plnkr.html with 1.0.0-alpha.24 was:

```
Template parse warnings:
The <template> element is deprecated. Use <ng-template> instead ("[WARNING ->]<template ngFor [ngForOf]="parts" let-part let-isOdd="odd"><span *ngIf="isOdd" class="{{highlightClas"): ng:///NgbTypeaheadModule/NgbHighlight.html@0:0
```

This was misleading since the code uses the `<ng-template>`, not the `<template>` element as claimed in the warnings.

The first lines of the error messages were:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'templateRef' of undefined

ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_ {view: Object, nodeIndex: 3, nodeDef: Object, elDef: Object, elView: Object}

Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read property 'templateRef' of undefined ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read property 'templateRef' of undefined

Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'templateRef' of undefined
```

Hopefully when other people get these messages they will find this thread.

It would be helpful if the warning and error message were not so misleading and unclear.