# How to sync Angular CLI versions between 2 computers?

Tags: angular, command-line-interface

I move an Angular CLI folder with a project back and forth between 2 computers as part of a local backup process.  One computer displays the following when running the Angular program:

> Your global Angular CLI version (1.0.1) is greater than your local
>   version (1.0.0). The local Angular CLI version is used.
>
> To disable this warning use "ng set --global warnings.versionMismatch=false".

The only part of this that I know how to find is

> ```
> "@angular/cli": "1.0.0",
> ```
>
> in package.json, which I assume is the local version.

What does one do to bring the two computers to the same versions of local and global Angular CLI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the most recent version on both follow the instructions [on the Angular CLI GitHub page](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli)

```
rm -rf node_modules dist # use rmdir /S/Q node_modules dist in Windows Command Prompt; use rm -r -fo node_modules,dist in Windows PowerShell
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
npm install
```

Comment: This was helpful, and I'm accepting this as the answer even though I haven't been able to test it.  To deal with the ng-bootstrap issue at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43874390/angular-2-ng-bootstrap-ngbtabset-erroruncaught-in-promise-typeerror-cannot/45284949#45284949 I created a new local CLI folder for the program, and it had `"@angular/cli": "1.2.3",`